# Open source Java map viewer that work with osm files or osm pre-downloaded tiles

Tags: java, mapping, openstreetmap

I am developing a desktop application that needs to display maps with some overlays. I have both .osm file of the area and pre-downloaded tiles from OSM. Did somebody knows an open source tool for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/

Great library that I've used with great success.  Particularly good for offline mode.  The dev is moving away from the tile downloader classes but you can still find them in the old jar.

Comment: This is for android. I want JSE version.

Comment: You should probably try to be specific in your question since your question says JAVA which means mapsforge or locus would work great.  Your answer is also very easily found online.   http://www.ns-tech.co.uk/blog/2008/08/using-openstreetmap-overview-part-2-javascript-apis/ has a tutorial.  Try mapstraction if you really aren't afraid of work, I'd say it's the leader right now.

Comment: I was clear and specific. I said Java for desktop ...However thank you for introducing me the MapsForge! As you said it is a great library!

Comment: For sure, be sure to download the advanced map viewer and samples from the website, they are great for examples and I've actually just built straight off the advanced map viewer before, it has a lot of nice features coded into it already.  Good luck!